# Why is the output an empty list, when I call a function that skips nodes in a linked-list?

Tags: python, linked-list

I am writing code to answer the following [LeetCode question](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-linked-list-elements/):

> Given the head of a linked list and an integer `val`, remove all the nodes of the linked list that has `Node.val == val`, and return *the new head*
>
> #### Example 1
>
> ```
> Input: head = [1,2,6,3,4,5,6]
>        val = 6 
> Output: [1,2,3,4,5]
> ```

This is my code:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        curr= head
        dummy=ListNode(0)
        prev=dummy

        def skipper(prev,curr):  
            if curr.val == val:
                curr = curr.next
            else:
                prev.next = curr
                temp = curr
                prev = temp
                curr = curr.next

            while prev.next:
                if prev.next.val == val:
                    prev.next = curr
            return curr

        while curr: 
            return skipper(prev,curr)


        return dummy.next
```

For the above code, I know that the logic works, because when I replace the inner function `def skipper(prev,curr)` with just `while curr`, and remove the `while curr` at the bottom of the code, then the code passes all tests.

But I want to understand how to use/call a function within a function.

The skipper function is simply meant to run through the linked list one node at a time, and 'remove' or relink the nodes so as to skip any nodes that have the same value as val.

My issue is I am not sure what to return inside the skipper function, and as a default I have returned curr- since to me this makes some sense.

But when I run the above code, I get a timeout error.

Comment: `skipper` doesn't return anything

Comment: don't use "next" as identifier, it is a python function. What is "dummy"? How do you run this code?

Comment: Thanks Sayse- I have added a return curr now. But the output still isn't quite right. But when I run it on paper it should give the correct result.

Comment: Yuri I have changed it to nxt- is it okay now?

Comment: @hefufhiwh Could you tell what you want your ```skipper``` function to do ?

Comment: I have edited the code slightly, but I want skipper to skip a node, so e.g. A->B->C   and if curr=B and curr.val==val, then I want to call skipper, which reconnects the nodes so that A-> C ; so we 'delete' B

Comment: I think I just realised the mistake- I am doing prev=curr then changing curr in the next line!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues in your code (as it was first posted):

- `return skipper(prev,curr)` is going to exit the loop, but there might be more nodes to be removed further down the list. `skipper` only takes care of a sub sequence consisting of the same value, but it will not look beyond that. The list is not necessarily sorted, so the occurrences of the value are not necessarily grouped together.
- Be aware that the variable `prev` in `skipper` is not the same variable as the other, outer `prev`. So the assignment `prev=curr` in `skipper` is quite useless
- Unless the list starts with the searched value, `dummy.next` will always remain `None`, which is what the function returns. You should initialise `dummy` so it links to `head` as its next node. In your updated code you took care of this, but it is done in an obscure way (in the `else` part). `dummy` should just be initialised as the head of the whole list, so it is like any other node.

In your updated code, there some other problems as well:

- `while prev.next:` risks to be an infinite loop, because it continues while `prev` is not the very last node, but it also doesn't move forward in that list if its value is not equal to the searched value.

I would suggest doing this without the `skipper` function. Your main loop can just deal with the cases where `current.val == val`, one by one.

Here is the corrected code:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        dummy = ListNode(0, head)  # Link to head!
        prev = dummy

        while curr: 
            if curr.val == val:    
                prev.next = curr.next  # This is all that needs to happen
            else: 
                prev = curr
            curr = curr.next  # This should happen in both cases
            # The loop invariant is: prev.next == curr

        return dummy.next
```

I don't see a benefit in having a separate `skipper` function, as in the end it will have to do all that the main function will have to do: i.e. find the occurrences of `val` and skip them.

If you really want a sub function, then maybe do:

```
class Solution:
    def removeElements(self, head: ListNode, val: int) -> ListNode:
        curr = head
        dummy = ListNode(0, head)
        prev = dummy

        def skipper(curr):
            while curr is not None and curr.val == val:
                curr = curr.next
            return curr
        
        while curr: 
            if curr.val == val:    
                prev.next = skipper(curr)
            else: 
                prev = curr
            curr = prev.next

        return dummy.next
```

Comment: thanks again trincot for the explanation, I understand now. A quick question about reassigning variables: I can see an issue with doing prev=curr then curr=curr.next right after; as prev points to curr, which we are changing straight away! Someone suggested the solution temp=curr, prev=temp then curr=curr.next; and in this way prev doesn't get reassigned to curr.next. But I don't see how this is the case, because when you do curr=curr.next; this changes curr, and so won't this also change temp and prev as a result??

Comment: No, `prev=curr; curr=curr.next` is not a problem. The second assignment will have no effect on `prev`. It is a different thing, when you *mutate* an object, like if after those assignments I would do `prev.next.val = 10`, then I will have modified the object that also `curr` is referring to, so what ever happens to `prev.next.val` happens to `curr.val` and vice versa, as `prev.next` and `curr` reference the same object. But *assigning* to a variable, will never impact anything else than that variable.

Comment: Hi Trincot, I was just going through your above code with the sub function. And I wanted to confirm something- the skipper function returns curr; so does this curr then take the place of "skipper(curr)" in the line prev.next=skipper(curr)